# Concatenating strings retrieved from form $_Post in php

Tags: php, string, forms, post, concatenation

I am posting a string through an HTML form with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
         <input name="message" 
         type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
         </form>
         </body>
         </html>
```

The code for test.php is the following:

```
   <?php
   $string1 = '$_POST["message"]';
   $og_url = "http://thepropagator.com/facebook/testapp/issue.php?name=".$string1;
echo $og_url;
   ?>
```

The problem I'm having is that the posted string "$string1" does not seem to be showing at the end of the URL "http://thepropagator.com/facebook/testapp/issue.php?name=" that I am trying to concatenate it with. Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `$string1 = $_POST['message'];`, no quotes. Though I'd expect your code to come up with `http://thepropagator.com/facebook/testapp/issue.php?name=$_POST["message"]` url.